# Sort data in the vertical-stack in the victory stack

Tags: react-native, victory-charts, victory-stack

Is there any way, through which the data can be sorted in the vertical bar, in which the biggest value (y-axis) ends up at the bottom?

Here is my code

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const getBarData = () => {
      return [1, 2,3,4].map((k) => {
        return [
          { x: 1, y: k*20 },
          { x: 2, y: k*30 },
          { x: 3, y: k*10 },
        ];
      });
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <VictoryChart domainPadding={{ x: 50 }} width={400} height={400}>
            <VictoryGroup offset={20} style={{ data: { width: 15 } }}>
              <VictoryStack colorScale={"red"}>
                {getBarData().map((data, index) => {
                  return <VictoryBar key={index} data={data}/>;
                })}
              </VictoryStack>
              <VictoryStack colorScale={"green"}>
                {getBarData().map((data, index) => {
                  return <VictoryBar key={index} data={data}/>;
                })}
              </VictoryStack>
              <VictoryStack colorScale={"blue"}>
                {getBarData().map((data, index) => {
                  return <VictoryBar key={index} data={data}/>;
                })}
              </VictoryStack>
            </VictoryGroup>
          </VictoryChart>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, mountNode);
```

[image]

I have used the victory stack and victory group with the victory bar, but when I am using the sortKey and sortOrder inside the Victory bar, the graph is sorted horizontally not vertically.